# Find an estimate of the percentage of students failing in exactly one subject, and also find an unbiased estimate of its variance

Tags: estimation, sampling, survey-sampling

The following describes summary statistics for performance in examination
of a random sample of 50 students from a population of 250
students of a certain school.

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
 & \text{Passed in English} & \text{Failed in English} &  \\
\hline
\text{Passed in Maths} & 23 & 17  \\
\text{Failed in Maths} &  3 &  7 \\
\end{array}
$$
**(a)** Find an estimate of the percentage of students failing in exactly
one subject, and also find an unbiased estimate of its variance

**(b)** If it is further known that overall 202 students have passed in
Mathematics, how will you modify the estimate of the percentage
in (a) above?

I am a total newbie in sampling and any kind of help shall be appreciated.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Answer (score 1):

If simple random sampling without replacement has been employed to drawn the sample, then usual results apply: $\hat{p} = \frac{a}{n} $, where $a= 3+17 =20$ is the number of successes and $n=50$ is the sample size.

The variance estimator is  $v(\hat{p}) = \frac{N-n}{N}\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n-1}$

**References**

Cochran, W. G. (1977). Sampling Techniques: 3d Ed. Wiley.

Comment: Please be cautious about providing complete answers to homework questions. Our policy is to provide hints only (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)).

Comment: @gung Its a one liner answer and plus as i have said , that this is the first time i m seeing this kind of question

Comment: It's OK. My comment is for future reference. The point is to provide hints, not do their HW for them, no matter how simple the question seems.

Comment: @gung You're right, I didn't see the [self-study] tag so I didn't think of it. Thank you.